# Rosserial Arduino custom message not being generated

Tags: ros-melodic, catkin, sensor-msgs, message, ros-lib

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have made a custom message called gas_msg.msg. It is located in a package named gas_sensor_msg. The custom message has been created with catkin_make. I am now trying to make the custom message files in the Arduino libaries using the command "rosrun rosserial_arduino make_libraries.py ~/Arduino/libraries/ gas_sensor_msg". I first delete the old ros_lib before running the command, but it is not creating header files for the new custom message. It is only replacing the old default messages.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/378040/rosserial-arduino-custom-message-not-being-generated/) by [sathyas](https://answers.ros.org/users/74314/sathyas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2021-05-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You probably need to run `source devel/setup.bash` and then you need to `rosrun rosserial_arduino make_libraries.py ~/Arduino/libraries/ gas_sensor_msg`.
The messages generated by catkin_make are in the devel directory if you do not install it, and will not be included in the ros_lib creation unless you can reference them.

---

Originally posted by [miura](https://answers.ros.org/users/59801/miura/) with karma: 1908 on 2021-05-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sathyas](https://answers.ros.org/users/74314/sathyas/) on 2021-05-10**:
This worked! Tysm

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2021-05-11**:
@sathyas if this answered your question, then please accept the answer by clicking on the checkmark next to the answer